# Using downloadTask method in a wrapper class

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement a library for handling web service related operations in iOS(using swift). I have 2 elements mainly handling the request from a user. One is A(not the actual name, it is of struct type) which I will be exposing to the user and other one is B(it is of class type) in which I will do all the  network operations. I am using completion  handler to indicate the status of the operations.  As of now data task with GET and POST is done. Now I have to code for downloadTask and uploadTask. The problem is downloadTask has several delegate methods. What are the things I need to pass from to class A and how?

Comment: If you really need the delegate based API write your own protocol / delegate pattern to notify. But maybe the block based API is sufficient. In this case write your own completion handler.

Comment: As of now I am trying to implement the block based implementation. I may ask few silly things(sorry for that). In class B(which handles the download task method and related delegate methods) I take a reference of class A and in each delegate methods for downloadTask, I change the properties of class B. (like downloadProgress and file URL). Is that a good way to approach or do you recommend any other ways?

Comment: If you want to provide download progress you have to use the delegate based API so write a protocol and appropriate delegate methods that the target class can adopt.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions man @vadian